# Max Connection pool

Tags: hibernate, jboss, ejb

I have a situation where i am getting max connection size reached. when working with oracle database using JBOSS server. Now the default size set in the domain of my jboss is 10 and it has  been working for a long time. But today im getting this error so first i tried to increase the connection pool from 10 to 30 but i still get thesame error.
After a while of thought i decided to ask this question here.

```
When is it right to increase connection pool size and how do we know this is right situation? 
How do we debug such a situation where there is not much load on the server but we get such error, what are the things to look at first in approaching this problem.
```

I am not looking for one specific answer but to broaden my knowledge how to go about solving such a problem Thank you.